# How to create an enums service in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, web, dependency-injection, ember-data

I want to create a service of enums in ember so that I only have to inject it to use it everywhere. Is there a good way to do it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh I found the solution. 
I've doing the right thing but the ember serve is not that smart..

Steps:

1. just use: ember g service enums
2. and add an initializer with: ember g initializer enums
3. in newly created enums initializer, put 

   `export default {
     name: 'titleService',
     initialize: function(application) {
       application.inject('route', 'enums', 'service:enums');
     }
   };`
4. restart the ember server and you get yourself an enums service

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work also, in your service code you add Enumerable mixin

```
export default Ember.Service.extend(Ember.Enumerable, {
  length: // ...
  nextOjbect: // ..
  next: // ...
  value: // ...
}
```

According to the docs you will need to implement nextObject() and length. Ember service is just Ember object so I think this is much cleaner solution

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#toc_writing-your-own-enumerable

Let me know if this worked for you....